# How to block writing in input text?

Tags: javascript

I just creating a booking system and I want that the users will choose a date from the calender and it'll show in input text - that I did!

Now I want to block the writing in the input text (just bring to calender writes there when the user choose a date).
How do I do it? I guess JavaScript, but how? I dont know JS very wall..

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if we helped you out! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="someId" disabled="disabled" />
```

The disabled property will prevent any user input, but you can still write to it via your javascript calendar method.

Comment: using readonly as in below mentioned answer is a much better option

Answer (score 45):

Give your element the `readonly` attribute, this will disallow users to type anything into it. However, you will still be able to write to add through javascript for example when a date is chosen. Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" readonly="readonly">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('txt');
el.value = "Testing......";
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/iluci3)

Answer (score 5):

For those who wants to prevent typing but not having the disabled style, can try:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return false;"/>
```

Comment: This is not going to work if the user tries to paste something